# Gameobject Position Can't Follow Parent Position Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got problem when set position of child to as it parent position.

Below the screenshot :

[image]

My script :

```
RightNext.transform.GetChild (0).gameObject.transform.SetParent (TemporaryPage.transform,false); // TemporaryPage = Cherry Cake

RightNext.transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<RectTransform> ().localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
            RightNext.transform.GetChild (0).gameObject.transform.parent = RightNext.transform;
            RightNext.transform.GetChild (0).transform.position = RightNext.transform.position;
```

And i put it in update to make sure the position is not changing.

Why my child position is not inside and same position with parent even i have set it to the same position with parent ?

Thanks

Dennis

Comment: Is your child object Position set to 0?

Comment: No.. When set it to 0 what i am using ? .Localposition or .position ?

Comment: On the transform component of the child gameobject

Comment: You gotta use RectTransform. Because they are ui objects.

Comment: @NahuelIanni I set the position(0,0,0) the position is moved, but move to the center of screen not center of parent object. EmreE, i have already set RectTransform to the child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
RightNext.transform.GetChild (0).transform.position = RightNext.transform.position;
```

to this:

```
RightNext.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = Vector2.zero;
```

OR this:

```
RightNext.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = RightNext.transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position;
```

Edit after your comment: the two lines I suggested are used to make the child pivot point coincide with the parent pivot point, I thought you wanted that and not to always place the child object pivot at the center of the parent object regardless of its pivot.

With the line you suggested (you can use the 2D version since we're dealing with UI):

```
RightNext.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
```

you put the child pivot at the center of the parent object, so you need to set the child pivot at (0.5,0.5).

However, I strongly suggest to get references to the RectTransform of both parent and child in the Start method (or after instantiating a new child), to avoid the constant use of the GetComponent method inside Update, since it's a slow method.

Comment: I already try that. The position is moved but not inside parent center position. So I Add this RightNext.transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<RectTransform> ().anchoredPosition3D = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);  and this is worked. Please add this to the answer. I will tick it. Thanks